# Why do I need a temp file with pg_dump?

Tags: bash, postgresql, pg-dump

I have been receiving errors from [pgdumplib](https://pypi.org/project/pgdumplib/) and have boiled down the problem to how the output of `pg_dump` is redirected.

This is what I would like to do, but it consistently fails with `RuntimeError: Unsupported data format`:

```sh
F=/tmp/test_Fc_format.dump
ssh codimd "sudo -u codimd bash -c 'cd /; pg_dump -d codimd -Fc'" >$F
python -c "import pgdumplib; dump = pgdumplib.load('$F')"
```

I can work around the problem by redirecting the file on the remote machine. This sequence works consistently:

```sh
F=/tmp/test_Fc_format.dump
ssh codimd "sudo -u codimd bash -c 'cd /; pg_dump -d codimd -Fc >/tmp/934354 && cat /tmp/934354'" >$F
python -c "import pgdumplib; dump = pgdumplib.load('$F')"
```

Note that the only difference is that the second sequence adds  `>/tmp/934354 && cat /tmp/934354`, i.e. redirecting the output of `pg_dump` to a file on the remote machine first, and then sending that to stdout. In both cases, the resulting file is the same size (though not identical because the database is online).

Both local and remote machines run Ubuntu 20.04.

Why is this extra step necessary, and is there a better way to solve this issue?

**Update 1**:
This, too, gives the error:

```
F=/tmp/test_Fc_format.dump
ssh codimd "sudo -u codimd bash -c 'cd /; pg_dump -d codimd -Fc |tee /tmp/934354 >/dev/null && cat /tmp/934354'" >$F
python -c "import pgdumplib; dump = pgdumplib.load('$F')"
```

In other words, to work, `pg_dump` seems to require a redirect to a local file or the `-f` option.

**Update 2**:
Here is the full list of differences between the bad and good version of the database, after using `hd` on each (note `pg_dump` never produces the same output twice):

```
2c2
< 00000010  00 11 00 00 00 00 19 00  00 00 00 16 00 00 00 00  |................|
---
> 00000010  00 2e 00 00 00 00 19 00  00 00 00 16 00 00 00 00  |................|
349c349
< 000015c0  31 38 01 01 00 00 00 01  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |18..............|
---
> 000015c0  31 38 01 01 00 00 00 02  b0 30 00 00 00 00 00 00  |18.......0......|
370c370
< 00001710  31 34 01 01 00 00 00 01  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |14..............|
---
> 00001710  31 34 01 01 00 00 00 02  1e 5f 00 00 00 00 00 00  |14......._......|
387c387
< 00001820  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 b7 0b 00 00  |................|
---
> 00001820  00 00 02 21 d9 60 00 00  00 00 00 00 b7 0b 00 00  |...!.`..........|
399c399
< 000018e0  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 bf 0b 00 00 00 01  |................|
---
> 000018e0  02 91 0a 4c 01 00 00 00  00 00 bf 0b 00 00 00 01  |...L............|
412,413c412,413
< 000019b0  03 00 00 00 32 32 30 01  01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  |....220.........|
< 000019c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 ba 0b  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00  |................|
---
> 000019b0  03 00 00 00 32 32 30 01  01 00 00 00 02 ce 0b 4c  |....220........L|
> 000019c0  01 00 00 00 00 00 ba 0b  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00  |................|
425c425
< 00001a80  35 01 01 00 00 00 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |5...............|
---
> 00001a80  35 01 01 00 00 00 02 0b  ee 4c 01 00 00 00 00 00  |5........L......|
438c438
< 00001b50  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 b8 0b 00 00  |................|
---
> 00001b50  00 00 02 28 ee 4c 01 00  00 00 00 00 b8 0b 00 00  |...(.L..........|
456c456
< 00001c70  01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 c7 0b  |................|
---
> 00001c70  01 00 00 00 02 45 ee 4c  01 00 00 00 00 00 c7 0b  |.....E.L........|
```

**Update 3**:
It turns out that this has nothing to do with ssh. I think `pg_dump` requires a seekable file as output. Here I demonstrate that inserting `|cat` before redirecting the output file causes the file to be corrupted. If true, is this a bug in `pg_dump`?

```
$ pg_dump -d codimd -Fc >/tmp/good
$ python3 -c "import pgdumplib; dump = pgdumplib.load('/tmp/good')"
$ # no error
$ pg_dump -d codimd -Fc |cat >/tmp/bad
$ python3 -c "import pgdumplib; dump = pgdumplib.load('/tmp/bad')"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pgdumplib/__init__.py", line 24, in load
    return dump.Dump(converter=converter).load(filepath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pgdumplib/dump.py", line 254, in load
    raise RuntimeError('Unsupported data format')
RuntimeError: Unsupported data format
$
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222342/discussion-on-question-by-bitinerant-why-do-i-need-a-temp-file-with-pg-dump).

Answer (score -2):

Some testing on my end:

```
F=test_dmp.out

pg_dump -d test -U postgres -Fc > $F | ls -al test_dmp.out 
-rw-r--r-- 1 aklaver users 0 Sep 30 14:06 test_dmp.out

pg_dump -d test -U postgres -Fc > temp_file.out && cat temp_file.out > $F | ls -al test_dmp.out 
-rw-r--r-- 1 aklaver users 97488 Sep 30 14:08 test_dmp.out

pg_dump -d test -U postgres -Fc -f $F | ls -al test_dmp.out 
-rw-r--r-- 1 aklaver users 97488 Sep 30 14:08 test_dmp.out
```

I know that not an answer as to why `>` does not work, but it gives an alternative. For some reason `>` creates an empty file. The other options do not.

**UPDATE**.

It seems to have something to do with the `SSH` transfer:

```
F=test_dump.out
#Using local only.
pg_dump -d test -U postgres -Fc > $F
python -c "import pgdumplib; dump = pgdumplib.load('$F'); print('Database: {}'.format(dump.dbname))"
Database: test

#Using SSH, different database
ssh arkansas "sudo -u aklaver bash -c 'cd /; pg_dump -d redmine -U postgres -Fc'" >$F

python -c "import pgdumplib; dump = pgdumplib.load('$F'); print('Database: {}'.format(dump.dbname))"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/aklaver/py_virt/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pgdumplib/__init__.py", line 24, in load
    return dump.Dump(converter=converter).load(filepath)
  File "/home/aklaver/py_virt/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pgdumplib/dump.py", line 254, in load
    raise RuntimeError('Unsupported data format')
RuntimeError: Unsupported data format
#Though the file itself ends up being ok. The below does not error out.
#There seems to be something asynchronous going on. In other words 
#pgdumplib is reading the file before it is complete.
pg_restore  -f test.sql test_dump.out
```

Comment: I don't understand how this gives us an alternative, unless you mean `pg_dump ... -f ...`. Also, in the `| ls -al test_dmp.out` makes no sense to me - pipe to ls?

Comment: Yes use the `-f` switch. The `ls` was just to show that the `>` creates an empty file, whereas the other options do not.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, using both `>` and `|` makes no sense. Keep in mind that both sides of a pipeline **run at the same time**. So, for example: `(sleep 1; echo hello) >file | ls -l file` _also_ shows your file as 0-byte, because the `ls` happens before the `sleep` finishes and the `echo` gets a chance to start. You can expect similar behavior for any other command where the thing on the left-hand side can take longer than `ls` needs to run before it's ready to start writing output.

Comment: (Also, combining these two directives is giving the shell conflicting information on where stdout is supposed to go; `>` says to send it to a file, `|` says to send it to the write end of a FIFO with the program on the right-hand side's stdin connected to the read end of same).

Comment: Thank you for testing this. It looks to me like you have replicated the problem I'm seeing, but I don't see anything about *why*. Also, I don't understand "pgdumplib is reading the file before it is complete". This can't be because the Python command isn't even run until after the ssh command completes.

Comment: I said that because the `test_dump.out` file at some point is valid as I could do `pg_restore  -f test.sql test_dump.out` and it created a valid plain text.sql.  Just now I reversed the order and the `pg_restore` still worked and `pgdumplib` did not, so that knocked the 'complete' theory in the head. It is looking more and more like this is a `pgdumplib` issue. Still sneaking up on the why?

Comment: Hmm. Took a pg_dump(redmine_dmp.out) on the remote machine and did `scp` back to my machine. The database is static, so did the `ssh arkansas ...` command. The files are identical in size. I then did `vimdiff <(xxd redmine_dmp.out) <(xxd test_dump.out)`.  I can see difference between second line in each. Still `pg_restore` does not care only `pgdumplib` . I would set up a test database on your remote that is static and see what you see.